# OpenSSL SSL_write throws Writing failed

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to lean OpenSSL (1.1.1). But during writing i get Writing Failed (obtained from ERR_print_errors). The handshake was successful (returned 1). I'm also trying to limit this to TLS 1.3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char * request = argv[1]
    int request_len = strlen(request)

    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
    if (ctx == NULL) {ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);}
    long options = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | 
        SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | 
        SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | 
        SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2;
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, options);
    SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    if (ssl == NULL) {ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);}

    BIO * bio = BIO_new_connect("google.com:443")
    if (bio == NULL) {ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);}
    SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
    if (SSL_connect(ssl) != 1) {ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);}
    if (SSL_write(ssl, request, request_len) !=1) {ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);}
}
```

Comment: Please give more details about the error, i.e. use [SSL_get_error](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html) as documented.

Comment: I used `printf("%d\n",SSL_get_error(ssl, err));` after SSL_write. The error printed was 0.

Comment: So where did you get this "Writing failed" then you claim to have gotten? I cannot see anything like this in your code. I recommend you share the full code to get something reproducible, including the input in your program.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to specify. I used ERR_print_errors. That there is the full code. I just removed IFs that check incorrect output, and call ERR_print_errors in case that happens.

Comment: Did you actually **read** [the `SSL_write()` documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_write.html)?  You don't seem to bother checking the return code from `SSL_write()` - or even `SSL_connect()` for that matter.

Comment: @ZergOvermind:  *"That there is the full code"* - it is not. It's having syntax errors, there is no `main`, no header files and no information what `argv[1]` contains. It is also still missing the explanation what kind of error you get since you claim to get some error message which is not in code. Once I fill in the missing pieces with the correct stuff it works perfectly for me. For now I've voted your question down since you don't seem to be willing to provide the full information to reproduce the issue - which makes answering your question impossible (like I said - it worked for me).

Comment: Also you need to specify OpenSSL version; only 1.1.1 (including all patches) supports TLS1.3, but 1.1.1 doesn't implement SSL2 (ever) so you don't need to exclude that, and default build omits SSL3 so you may not need to exclude that, but you _do_ need to exclude TLS1.1 (SSL_OP_NO_TLS1_1).

Comment: I edited, and now i see the error. I incorrectly compared the SSL_write output. Feel free to add answer. Sorry about the skipped code, it made the question useless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SSL_write` output is incorrectly checked. It outputs positive length of send data.

It should instead be

```
if (SSL_write(ssl, request, request_len) < 1) {ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);}
```